# 'edit ' is not recognised as an internal command,operable program or batch file in dos why?

Tags: windows-xp, text-editing, sp3

After installing Oracle in my system, I can not edit txt files in the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it has not be deleted (unlikely) your path may have been amended not to include your windows system32 directory which is where edit.com should be found

So %windir%\system32\edit.com should start it regardless of the path settings.

You can check/change your path on the Environment Variables section which is found on the Advanced tab of your System Properties. (ie Right-Click on My-Computer and select Properties)